# Apache redirects overwriting inconsistently

Tags: apache, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have multiple rewrite rules configured for a domain, to serve specific articles by 301ing to a new domain, and two catch-all rules for rules that don't match

```
RewriteEngine on
# Rewrites for specific testdomain1.com pages to a new server
RewriteRule "^/2018/04/01/Article-1/$" "http://testdomain2.com/Article-1" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule "^/2018/04/02/Article-2/$" "http://testdomain2.com/Article-2" [R=301,L]
# Catch-all for images (pass them through)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
# Redirect for all other matches
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://testdomain2.com/ [R=301,L]
```

The issue I am running into is that while Article-1 matches fine and serves a 301, requests to Article 2 appear to be caught up by the last rule in the redirect. I'm not entirely sure why this is occurring, but any advice would be helpful, before I add the remaining 6400 entries to the redirect file.

To help with debugging, here's the markup for a curl call to the article 2 test path:

```
curl -0 http://www.testdomain1.com/2018/04/02/Article-2/ -o example.html

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://www.testdomain2.com/$%224">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at www.testdomain1.com Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Comment: I am wondering if you have a problem with the URL you are requesting. Could you show us a curl of "<domain.com>/2018/04/01/Article-1", or better yet, increase the logging verbosity of apache and post the logs?

Comment: I added a curl example. I'll check into altering the logging to provide more details.

Comment: The second rewrite rule is doesn't have this: ` [R=301,L]` at the end?

Comment: I forgot to add it above, but it is present.

Comment: The redirect response to that curl example did not come as result of the above rules.